# What would be a reason to make all the reference parameters const?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, coding-style, constants

Is there a good reason to make all or most of the reference parameters const?

I was reading Google C++ Style Guide and I could not understand why "All parameters passed by reference must be labeled const." (see [here](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Reference_Arguments#Reference_Arguments))

1. Can anyone provide some justification for that?
2. According to this guide, should I use only pointers when a method/function is supposed to change an object?

I know there are a lot of people who criticize this guide, as in this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20140503193653-3046051-why-google-style-guide-for-c-is-a-deal-breaker). I am looking for an answer that would give a logical argument for the above-specified "must", but not just argue that Google is wrong.

Comment: They provide their own justification for it, that people who follow _their_ convention will assign different semantics to variables passed in as references versus those passed in as a pointer. It's their style/convention guide, and if you disagree with it, that's all well and good, but this question invites pretty much arbitrary answers that would go into just as many different coding convention guides.

Comment: To paraphrase Oscar Wilde, "[Style] is a form of ugliness so intolerable that we have to alter it every six months"

Comment: Additionally, passing something by reference can be faster (doesn't require a copy of the variable/object), so per optimization, using references might be a good idea sometimes (and therefore, when you still don't want to modify the original value, using `const` is logical). This of course makes it a bit confusing to tell whether they use it to change the input-variable/object, or to just optimize. Const-references kind of solves this, in my opinion.

Comment: Why was my question down voted? I really didn't understand a concept and I asked for help. It is not a duplicate and I think I formulated it right, since "the rationale in their document" was not clear enough for me. If someone down votes it, please explain why.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is a programming Q&A, not Google internal policy Q&A. In C++, we have `std::swap`, `std::getline`, `std::regex_search`, and many other functions that modify by-reference parameters.

Comment: @Cubbi, thank you for clearing that out. I really love this site and I now feel bad because of my question. I tried to reformulate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that they're arguing that non-`const` references allow mutable reference semantics without making it obvious in the code. When using a pointer, you explicitly have to perform indirection (with `*`), which makes it obvious that you're utilising reference semantics.

I wouldn't say this is a particularly great argument. Instead, I recommend avoiding mutable reference semantics all together (whether reference or pointer), if you can. Value semantics are much easier to reason about. Additionally, non-`const` reference arguments have traditionally been used for output parameters, when a single return type is not enough. These days, we can easily return a `std::tuple` if we want multiple outputs.

I would say both non-`const` references and pointer parameters don't really have much of a place in modern C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

It is just to clarify input and output. Input values should be taken in as const references (because they are pure input, they shouldn't change the value of the argument) or by value. Outputs should be pointers. Whenever you see a pointer, it is output (or an input-output). Whenever you see a reference, it is an input.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the reason why non-`const` references are disallowed is that it makes it easy to tell when an argument might be modified: if you pass in a pointer to it, then it might be modified, but if you pass it by reference, it definitely won't be.

```
foo(bar, &baz); // baz may be modified, bar will not be modified
```

If `foo` were allowed to take an argument by non-`const` reference, then it might modify an argument even though the argument's address isn't taken explicitly anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. To make it clear at the call site that the argument may be modified.
2. Yes.

It's not actually such a bad idea, it happened to me several times to be surprised by functions changing the variables passed as arguments without me noticing at first sight.